# Scrambling data for a Java program in non-reverse engineerable way

Tags: java, obfuscation

How can I obfuscate plain text data so that a Java program able to deobfuscate it is difficult to reverse engineer?  That is, there should be no easy way to figure out how to descramble the data yourself by decompiling/disassembling the JVM code for the program.

I realize this is impossible if a bad guy is determined enough.  Just want to make it as hard as possible.

The only idea I have is a native extension implementing an encryption algorithm with the key stored in a quirky way, not just a simple string. But would *really* like to avoid a native extension.

**Edit**

I vehemently disagree with the down and close votes.  This is a real problem.  The app is fielded to thousands of high school kids.  To scramble the data, it currently implements RC4 encryption (in Java) with the key embedded in the code.  Smart kids are able to decompile this and use the decompilation to write Java that reads other kids' data files.  This in turn allows various forms of cheating.  We need a simple, cheap way to make it harder to deduce the scrambling algorithm.  That's all.  We don't care about reverse engineering the rest of this 80k line app.  In fact it's open source. We just need to protect the single function that does the data descrambling.

Comment: Encrypt the data, and have your application decrypt it.  I don't believe you *require* a native extension, but you may want to look at the JCE Unlimited Strength JAR.

Comment: A very pricey option is Excelsior JET, which would essentially compile the java bytecode into a native executable (which turn makes it as hard to reverse engineer as a C++ app).

Comment: This is screaming XY problem. You're trying to keep different users' information secret from each other? Use asymmetric encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that a program can decode, a program can decode. Any Java program can be decompiled. Even storing the data remotely won't work since after the data's downloaded you're decrypting it, and that can be replicated or patched. If plaintext is ever exposed, it can be accessed. You can make it difficult to access, but in the words of a hacker many years ago: "Hey, great, it's copy-protected -- that means it comes with a free puzzle!"

Remember, there's a reason password storage typically uses trap-door cyphers and compares the cryptographically hashed values. And even that requires keeping the encrypted passwords somewhere that the user is absolutely unable to access.

Step back and reconsider your design.

Comment: Thanks but you're telling me nothing new.  There is no alternative design.

Comment: There is no robust implementation of this design. If it can be displayed, it can be copied. Even if you render the text via image manipulation, paint the pixels out of order, and otherwise make it "not text" until it hits the screen, they can still scrape the screen. Remember that time is something the kids can afford to invest far more of than you can; their time is cheaper than yours. Unless you give them *NO* access to the interior of the box, all you can do is delaying/annoying tactics. If they're sufficiently motivated, they will win. Period.

Comment: I know all this.  It's a war.  We escalate.  They escalate.  I have no expectation of a perfect answer, just the next escalation.